# Sending an individual push notification to a specific user of webview Android application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to send an individual push notification to a specific user of webview Android application?

I have a webview based Android application. Android 8 blocks all background processes and my application can not anymore check for messages every 5 minutes and to show push notifications is there are new messages. As I understand almost the only solution is to use firebase to show notifications.

My question is: can I send individual Firebase notifications to webview application users? If yes, how? People who login to my website from Android phones, enter their data in a login form that loads my website. It's not a Android login form. How can I at the same time login to Firebase and how Firebase will know that this user is already logged in if it's only a webwiew application?

Answer (score 0):

A webview is not capable of directly receiving Cloud Message payloads.  The only browsers that works with Cloud Messaging are those that [support the Push API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api).

What you can do instead is receive the payload in the native layer of your Android app (using a normal Android integration with a service that receives the payload), then proxy it to your webview as needed, using webview's ability to inject javascript into it (while it's visible).  This definitely is not a trivial amount of work.